# How do I validate a username/password in OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest?

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to store Windows credentials to login to an intranet webapp in a webview.

```
var login = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("Login", FileCreationMode.Private);
string username = login.GetString("username", null);
string password = login.GetString("password", null);

if (username != null && password != null)
    handler.Proceed(username, password);
```

But when the password is wrong it just keeps trying until the account is locked out.  How do I check that the `Proceed` was unsuccessful so I can reprompt the user to enter in new credentials.

Comment: did it go into "onReceivedSslError" ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT No it does not.

Comment: maybe you could make a count,for example when count >= 3,you call handler.Cancel

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I considered that.  But when would I reset it to 0? There's no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my suggestion:

```
int requestCount;
public override void OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, string host, string realm)
     {
         requestCount++;
         if(requestCount <3)
           {
             handler.Proceed(username, password);
           }
          else
           {
             //show a Dialog(with two edittext for input username and password) which notice credentials failure and reprompt the user to enter in new credentials
             //when you click Dialog's "Ok" reset requestCount to 0 and call "handler.Proceed(newUsername, newPassword);" 
             //when you click Dialog's "Cancel" call "handler.Cancel();"
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is saving incorrect password.

1. Starting from no username/password
2. After the user input username/password, check it. if correct
   saving it and if not start over.
3. Later, when username/password is required, fetch it and then check it.
4. if it work and logged, then we have done.
5. if it does not work clear the store and start over again